# IE Browser extension method for showing a new addon ICON on browser

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, atl, browser-extension, ieaddon

I have to place a icon/button on IE browser and on click of it i have to perform some operation.Which option do i need to use.

1. Shortcut menu extensions
2. Toolbars
3. Explorer Bars
4. Browser Helper Objects

Comment: Where exactly do you want to put that icon?

Comment: Anywhere at the top where it is visible for users. It should work for IE6 and above.

Comment: What do you mean by "the top"? Please be more specific.

Comment: where other addons are shown

Comment: Have you tried Crossrider ? You should be able to have a simple button implementation including in IE in matter of minutes (Note: Crossrider supports IE7 and above)